# SAS 9.3 DATETIME VARIABLE FORMAT AS DATE

Tags: datetime, sas

I have a datetime22.3 variable which I would like to display as date.

for eg I want to display 17JUL2006:00:00:00.000 as 07/17/2006

How do I do this?

Thanks.

---

additional info:

Thanks for all the replies.

### Actually, I tried to output it in the date format within proc sql. The output is being printed as `**********` (stars). I am not sure what is going on.

I am trying to use INTCK in the following manner but get error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
PROC FORMAT;
PICTURE DTFMT LOW-HIGH='%0m/%0d/%Y'  (DATATYPE=DATETIME);
RUN;

data want;
dt_val1='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'dt;
dt_val2='17AUG2012:00:00:00.000'dt;
format dt_val1 dt_val2 dt_val3 dtfmt.;
dt_val3=intck('MONTH',dt_val1,dt_val2);
put dt_val3;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply a standard date format directly against a datetime value, although there are some date formats you can prefix with 'DT' which will display a datetime as a date.  Unfortunately the MMDDYY format is not one of these, however you could use DTDATE9. which would format your datetime as '17JUL2006'.

Another option is create your own format using the PICTURE statement, the example below will display the datetime as required.

```
proc format;
picture dtfmt low-high='%0m/%0d/%Y' (datatype=datetime);
run;

data want;
dt_val='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'dt;
format dt_val dtfmt.;
run;
```

Comment: Keith,can you please look at my question towards the bottom? Hopefuly I am not making a stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I had to widen the column when viewing the table to see the value, is that your problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
put(datepart(datetimevariable),yymmdd10.)
```

Answer (score 2):

use the same princpiple in a data step

```
data _null_;
   a='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'd;
   put a;
   put 'formatted date='a MMDDYY10.;
run;
```

This is the output from my SAS 9.3

```
44   data _null_;
45   a = '17JUL2006:00:00:00:000'D;
46   put a;
47   put 'formatted ' a MMDDYY10.;
48   run;

16999
formatted 07/17/2006
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: You're creating variable 'a' as a date, not datetime. That format won't work against a datetime value.

Comment: I agree with your output, but you should be storing 'a' as '17JUL2006:00:00:00:000'DT to make it a datetime value

Answer (score 1):

Formatting dates in SAS can be tricky.  One method I've used in a macro is this:

```
/* get the date time */
%let start_date=%sysfunc(datetime().,10);
/* use the DATETIME informat to format the date */
%let fmt_start_date=%sysfunc(putn(&start_date, DATETIME.)); 
/* format the datetime as a date */
%put "&fmt_start_date."d;
```

There's a bunch of different ways to format dates.  You could also use the `FORMAT` statement if you're in a data step:

```
FORMAT STARTDATE YYMMDD10.;
```

In this case, the format of the column in the data step would give you YYYY-MM-DD and then you can separate the values and reconstruct from there.

There's additional information about SAS informats for dates here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_intervals_sect008.htm

And here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_intervals_sect009.htm

If you need more info or examples, please let me know.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *display* the variable's contents as a date (without changing the underlying value), use a FORMAT statement.

```
proc print;
    format dte mmddyys10.;
run;

proc means;
    class dte;
    format dte mmddyys10.;
run;
```

etc. Note that you can also put the FORMAT in a data step, in which case any uses of the variable will automatically pick it up.

```
data foo;
    format dte mmddyys10.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer from a duplicate question:

You need to convert original SAS DATETIME value (think of it as data type) to SAS DATE value using DATEPART() function and apply appropriate format:

```
proc sql; 
 create table work.abc2
 as select *, DATEPART(a.Billing_Dt) format ddmmyy10. as Bill_date
from abc;
quit;
```

So the point is, as Keith pointed above, to apply appropriate type of format (e.g. ddmmyy10. is the SAS Date format) to appropriate values = variable content (e.g. (unformatted) `10` is 11th January 1960 if used as date, while it's 01JAN60:00:00:10 if used as Datetime value), so you have to be sure what your values represent and convert the values if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
data want;
dt_val1='17JUL2006:00:00:00.000'dt;
dt_you_want=input(substr(put(dt_val1,datetime22.3),1,9),date9.);
format dt ddmmyy10.;
run;
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some the essential explanation to the answer here.

Answer (score -1):

Converts date/time var to char date var:

```
BLEndDatex = put(datepart(BLEndDateTime),yymmdd10.);
```

Create numeric sas date without time:

```
BLEndDate = mdy(SUBSTR(BLEndDatex,6,2),SUBSTR(BLEndDatex,9,2),SUBSTR(BLEndDatex,1,4));
```

Thanks to Rizier123  & Heemin posting above to the first portion.