# How to trim date variable in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a variable called DOJ( Date of Joining) and whose value is 10JAN12:00:00:00
I want to keep only date (i.e 10JAN12) How do I do that?

Note: DOJ is DATETIME18. in nature.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS 9.3 DATETIME VARIABLE FORMAT AS DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179801/sas-9-3-datetime-variable-format-as-date)

Comment: Depends on why you need to do this.  If it's just to display it differently then format DOJ as `dtdate7.`, which which display the datetime as ddmmmyy (e.g. 10JAN12).  Otherwise use `datepart` as per the answers provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All dates are stored as numbers internally by SAS.  A datetime is in seconds and a date is in days.  You need to convert to days using the `datepart()` function.

```
DOJ = datepart(DOJ);
```

Then change the format so that it is displayed as a date:

```
format DOJ date9.;
```

Answer (score 1):

`datepart()` function will do the job